# SQL Auto Increment several times in the same table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a basic HTML input form for an inbuilt admin panel on a website that I'm designing for a friend of mine. The idea is for him to post data scripted with PHP to the database, which is then spat back out onto the index page.

**The issue:**

Each entry obviously has its own column in the db (id, name, ep_num etc). The id is auto incremented into the database, the name is gathered as a `$_POST['name']`, however for ep_num, I would like to assign auto increments per name.

**EG:**

He posts "Hello" once, it is given the ep_num of "1"
He inputs "World" once, it is given the ep_num of "1"
He inputs "Hello" again, it is given the ep_num of "2"

I've had a long day at work, and believe that `mysql_insert_id()` may be what I'm looking for, I'm just struggling to put my brain to work and was hoping one of you guys to aid me.

Thanks in advance,
Rich

Comment: something about this: `insert into thetable (name, ep_num) select $_POST['name'], count(*)+1 from thetable where name=$_POST['name']`

Comment: Woah, lots of responses. I'll try this one first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
insert into t (name, ep_num) select 'b', count(*)+1 from t where name='b';
```

[Demo on sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/491ea/1)

Comment: This is exactly what I want. I'll try it again with your format, I didn't have much luck the first time but I was probably doing something idiotic.

Comment: Ok this is practically working however it's doing a double data entry. The ep_nums are going in in order eg 1,2,3,4 but it's inputting two entries with a 1 and 2 ep_num. I'll post my code in my question just in case.

Comment: Solved my issue. It was making a double entry because of my if statement on the SQL. Cheers for your help man.

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO table (name,ep_num) VALUES ("hello",1)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ep_num=ep_num+1;
```

To use this statement you need to make column name a primary key or a Unique index and make id an auto increment value if you are changing name to primary key. For more information on  [Duplicate key update](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

Comment: This suggestion is simply adding the name twice with the ep_num of one on both occasions, when I add another entry it does the same, keeping the same ep_num of "1".

Comment: You need to make sure name column is either a primary key or a unique and if you declare name as a primary key then make id is not a primary key you can alway have an auto increment on that