# How to make two columns auto increment in Sqlite

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I'm Using OID as a primary key with auto increment, but I want to make Txn No also auto increment. Is there any way to make it auto increment? I tried to use loop, but it seems doesn't work.

[image: Here is the picture]

When I click the "Save" one time, Next time should be Txn No "2", but I can't think of it, because I used OID to Auto increment, so Txn No can't use it.

**Here is My Code:**

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Person.db";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "Person_Table";
    public static final String COL_1 = "OID";
    public static final String COL_2 = "TxnNo";
    public static final String COL_3 = "Name";
    public static final String COL_4 = "Amount";
    public static final String COL_5 = "Date";
    public static final String COL_6 = "Description";
    public static final String COL_7 = "Description2";

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_NAME + " (OID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
                "TxnNo TEXT, Name TEXT, Amount INTEGER,Date TEXT, Description TEXT,Description2 TEXT)");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public boolean insertData(String TxnNo, String Name, String Amount, String Date, String Description, String Description2) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(COL_2, TxnNo);
        contentValues.put(COL_3, Name);
        contentValues.put(COL_4, Amount);
        contentValues.put(COL_5, Date);
        contentValues.put(COL_6, Description);
        contentValues.put(COL_7, Description2);
        long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
        if (result == -1)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First thing with SQLite AUTOINCREMENT doesn't actually increment the ID, using INTEGER PRIMARY KEY will result in much the same, other than when you've had 9223372036854775807 rows added. All AUTOINCREMENT does is enforce an increasing number (so when the largest rowid is reached an SQLITE FULL exception occurs), otherwise (without AUTOINCREMENT) free lower numbers can be allocated, thus potentially circumventing the SQLITE FULL exception.

In fact what INTEGER PRIMARY KEY (with or without AUTOINCREMENT) does is make the columnn alias of the rowid (a normally hidden column that is given a unique 64 bit signed integer).

One of the rules is that only a single column can have INTEGER PRIMARY KEY (or PRIMARY KEY) coded per table. Which is the issue that you are facing.

---

#### A Solution

A way to do what you wish is to utilise a **TRIGGER** that is triggered when a new row is inserted and use it to update the inserted row with a value that is suffixed with the **OID**. e.g.

```
CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS increment_tax_number 
    AFTER INSERT ON Person_Table 
    BEGIN
        UPDATE Person_Table SET TxnNo = 'Txn no '||new.OID WHERE OID =  new.OID;
    END;
INSERT INTO Person_Table VALUES(null,'not a valid tax number as yet','Fred',15000,'2018-01-01','blah','more blah');
INSERT INTO Person_Table VALUES(null,'not a valid tax number as yet','Bert',25000,'2018-03-04','blah','more blah');
SELECT * FROM Person_Table;
```

For a new table the above results in :-

[image]

**This solution could be incorporated by using** :-

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_NAME + " (OID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
            "TxnNo TEXT, Name TEXT, Amount INTEGER,Date TEXT, Description TEXT,Description2 TEXT)");
    db.execsql("CREATE TRIGGER If NOT EXISTS increment_tax_number     AFTER INSERT ON Person_Table 
BEGIN
    UPDATE Person_Table SET TxnNo = 'Txn no '||new.OID WHERE OID =  new.OID;
END");
}
```

- You would need to delete the App's data, uninstall the App or increase the version number (i.e. use `super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 2)`). Noting that you would lose any existing data. To not lose data would be more complicated.

#### A More efficient solution

Of course, there is also the option of just utilising the **OID** as it appears that you want the numeric part appended to **Txn No**, so there is no need to even have a column that is a waste. The **Txn No 1**,  **Txn No 2** etc can be generated when required.

e.g. The following will generate the Txn No purely from the OID column :-

```
SELECT Name, 'Txn No '||OID AS txn_no,Amount,Description,Description2 FROM Person_Table;
```

Resulting in :-

[image]

**To incorporate this solution you don't need to do anything other than use suitable queries (although you may wish to do away with the TxnNo column)**

#### More about AUTOINCREMENT

Using AUTOINCREMENT incurs overheads that are rarely required. The SQLite documentation includes :-

- > The AUTOINCREMENT keyword imposes extra CPU, memory, disk space, and
  >   disk I/O overhead and should be avoided if not strictly needed. It is
  >   usually not needed.
- [SQLite Autoincrement](https://sqlite.org/autoinc.html)

The overheads are because when AUTOINCREMENT is used the algorithm used to determine the new **rowid** adds a second stage of getting the respective row from the **sqlite_sequence** table and then using the higher of this and the highest **rowid** in the table (without AUTOINCREMENT just the highest rowid in the table is used). So the overheads are having to maintain and access this additional table for every insert.

As such it would be more efficient to define your table with either :-

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Person_Table (OID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,TxnNo TEXT, Name TEXT, Amount INTEGER,Date TEXT, Description TEXT,Description2 TEXT);
```

- If you decide to have the TxnNo column

or :-

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Person_Table (OID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, Name TEXT, Amount INTEGER,Date TEXT, Description TEXT,Description2 TEXT);
```

- If using the derived Txn No (more efficient solution)

Comment: where should I add those code? Sorry I'm a bit confused about this... I Create table in android studio.

Comment: @T3rranceLow answer amended to show how to incorporate the solutions. Up to you which way you go.

Answer (score 2):

You can't have 2 `AUTOINCREMENT` variables in the table. But now you declere: `TxnNo TEXT` it's very strange. 
You can look for these variants [sql-auto-increment-several](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32468620/sql-auto-increment-several-times-in-the-same-table)

Comment: He can update the second field after insert record because `db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues)` returns the id of record.

Comment: `AUTOINCREMENT` can be coded **ONCE** per table because it can only be coded with `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` which can only be coded once per table.

Comment: Ok, i think it my fault, may be you can't

Answer (score 2):

It may be, Sqlite not providing autoincrement for two column.
So i have several ways

- first of all you need to use "TxnNo" as INTEGER or LONG.
- at the time while you insert new record get Max "TxnNo" and increase it by 1. It is possible only if your whole database is synced in local. if it's not fully synced then its may occur duplication .
- Use "TxnNo" as LONG and set current time in milliseconds. this will give you unique number every time. no need to get max. I would like to prefer this way. cause i'm also using this way.