# Need some guidance for Sqlite database

Tags: sqlite, android-sqlite

I'm trying to create a database which have 8 roles. **Id** is **PK** with **auto increment**. After that those 4 **headers**, and one more **Unitcode(Trying to do auto increment also)**, **person in charge** and last is **LastTxnNo(Date)**.

[image: Picture]

Is there any problem if I'm using this all types? After that Is this database can put into android studio and call it out?

Comment: I don't understand your question: "Is there any problem if I'm using this all types?" That said, just looking at your create table stmt, it is confusing that one 'header' is an integer, while all the others are text.

Comment: You probably don't want that [autoincrement](https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html). It has a very specific meaning in sqlite that most tables don't need.

Comment: sorry about that. this was slip of my hand. suppose "text". @gregory

Comment: Id i need to make it auto increment and unitcode also. because It should be auto increase when i save the first record. when i create new. should be 2. @Shawn

Comment: Read that link. autoincrement does something a bit different in sqlite.

Comment: noted. thanks @Shawn

Comment: @T3rranceLow If you're concerned with how many text column you have, don't be. This is totally fine. Until you get more than say a hundred columns, there's nothing to worry about.

Comment: Okay. Thanks for helping me @gregory

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any problem if I'm using this all types?

No (unless you exceed 9223372036854775807 rows as explained below).

However, you very likely don't need to use `AUTOINCREMENT`. `AUTOINCREMENT` just says that the **id** must be larger that any others that have ever been used (unless you intervene).

The real wizardry as such, is when you code `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY`, That says that the column (i.e. id in your case) is an alias of the special/normally hidden **rowid** column. The **rowid** is an automatically generated unique 64bit signed integer, normally it will be 1 greater then the largest existing **rowid**, at first it will be 1.

With `AUTOINCREMENT` an additional table is required as this will hold the highest allocated **rowid**. A new **rowid** will normally be 1 greater than the highest existing or highest used **rowid**.  Due to having to read and maintain this extra table (sqlite_sequence) there are overheads associated with using `AUTOINCREMENT`. The recommendation is to not use `AUTOINCREMENT` unless it is needed.

`AUTOINCREMENT` due to the next **rowid** having to be larger than any existing will fail with an SQLITE_FULL exception should you reach 9223372036854775807 (limited of a 64 bit signed integer). Whilst without `AUTOINCREMENT` the algorithm used will attempt to find a lower unused/free id, so it may not fail.

You may wish to read [SQLite Autoincrement](https://sqlite.org/autoinc.html)

The UnitCode column may not be required. You suggest that you want it to copy the behaviour of the **rowid**. As such you could simply utilise the **rowid** (as was previously answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51997243/how-to-make-two-columns-auto-increment-in-sqlite/51997714#51997714)).

You could perhaps have another table for the PersonInCharge if the PersonIncharge can be in charge for more than 1 row in the Information table. e.g. you might have 10 bosses used throughout 1000 information rows. If that persons name is longer than 1 character then odds on referencing that person's name by the **rowid** of the PersonInCharge table, may be more efficient search wise and it could take up less space and memory. It would certainly adhere to the concept of normalisation (reduction of duplication of data).

> After that Is this database can put into android studio and call it
>   out?

Yes, an externally created database can be copied to the assets folder or a sub-directory of the assets folder. You then has a process that checks if the database exists and if not then the database can be copied from the assets folder to a suitable location (databases or normally located at `data/data/`*`your_package`*`/databases/`) the filename, as copied, should be the same as the database name (including file extension). You may find [SQLiteAssethelper](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/readystatesoftware/sqliteasset/SQLiteAssetHelper.java) of use.

Noting that **SQLiteAssetHelper** this expects the database file (the asset) to be in the **databases** folder/director of the **assets** folder/directory.